# How I can create local repository with module packages

Tags: linux, nginx, repository, oracle-linux

I have VM with Oracle Linux 8.
I need to create a local repository with nginx. But it's a module package. How I can download module packages from officially repository? If I downloaded with:

```
repotrack nginx
```

then an error appears when installing the package:

```
No available modular metadata for modular package 'nginx-1:1.16.1-2.0.1.module+el8.4.0+20188+a733e426.1.x86_64', it cannot be installed on the system
No available modular metadata for modular package 'nginx-filesystem-1:1.16.1-2.0.1.module+el8.4.0+20188+a733e426.1.noarch', it cannot be installed on the system
The downloaded packages were saved in cache until the next successful transaction.
You can remove cached packages by executing 'dnf clean packages'.
Error: No available modular metadata for modular package
```